# jQuery Datatables column count error - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0

Tags: datatables

This is a very common question, I'm aware. But I spent almost a day because I can't spot the error I have to post this. Can anyone see a mistake?

Markup :-

```
<table class="table align-items-center table-flush py-3" id="inquiry-select-table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="display:none">ID</th>
            <th scope="col" style="display:none">Version</th>
            <th scope="col" style="display:none">Created Date</th>
            <th scope="col" style="display:none">Created Time</th>
            <th scope="col" style="display:none">Updated Date</th>
            <th scope="col" style="display:none">Updated Time</th>
            <th scope="col" style="display:none">Client ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Client Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Knowledge Source</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS :-

```
var inquirySelectTable;
var inquirySelectTableColumns = [{
        data: "id"
    },
    {
        data: "version"
    },
    {
        data: "createdDate"
    },
    {
        data: "createdTime"
    },
    {
        data: "updatedDate"
    },
    {
        data: "updatedTime"
    },
    {
        data: "clientId"
    },
    {
        data: "clientName",
        defaultContent: "",
        className: "all"
    },
    {
        data: "knowledgeSource",
        defaultContent: "",
        className: "all",
        render: function (data, type, row) {
            switch (data) {
                case 'WOM':
                    return 'Word of mouth';
                case 'PAPER':
                    return 'Paper Article';
                case 'FB':
                    return 'Facebook';
                case 'GOOGLE':
                    return 'Google Ad';
                case 'EMAIL':
                    return 'Email';
                case 'SMS':
                    return 'SMS';
                default:
                    return 'Other'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        data: "description",
        defaultContent: "",
        className: "all"
    }
];

var inquiryColumnDefs = [{
    "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    "visible": false,
    "searchable": false
}];

var tableSizeFromFive = [
    [5, 10, 15, 25 - 1],
    [5, 10, 15, 25, "All"]
];

$(document).ready(function () {
    inquirySelectTable = $('#inquiry-select-table').DataTable({
        pagingType: "numbers",
        responsive: true,
        lengthMenu: tableSizeFromFive,
        columnDefs: inquirySelectTableColumns,
        columns: inquiryColumnDefs,
    });

    $.get("inquiries/getAllInquiries", function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        setGridData(inquirySelectTable, data);
    });
});

function setGridData(table, data) {
    table.clear();
    table.rows.add(data).draw();

    if (table.data().count() > 0) {
        $(".table-responsive").removeClass("disabled");
    } else {
        $(".table-responsive").addClass("disabled");
    }
}
```

The data received from the server :-

[image: JSON Response]

The error I'm getting is :-

[image: Datatables error]

According to https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4, since I'm getting an Integer as the parameter it means the column count does not match with the row count. But it seems ok to me. Does anyone see something I missed?

Comment: Just taking a shot here but possibly this: `var inquiryColumnDefs = [{
    "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], --This line right here, would explain it sayin unknown parameter 0 for row 0, column 0
    "visible": false,
    "searchable": false
}];` It would seem that targets: is expecting your `inquirySelectTableColumns ` array values.

Comment: @RyanWilson Actually I'm using the same column definitions ("visible": false, "searchable": false for 6 columns) for other data tables also and they work fine. And I just commented those 3 lines after you mentioned but the issue is still there.

Comment: Sorry then, I have nothing more to offer at this time.

Comment: Same as I :) Thanks for trying, mate

Comment: It could be because you have less columns listed in targets: than you do in your table headers, see documentation for this error here (https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4) Specific section text from linked documentation `The number of cells in the table does not satisfy the equation #cells = #columns * #rows (i.e. there are more columns defined in the header than in the table body, or vice-versa).`

Comment: Yeah, that's what bummed me out. the #cells = #columns * #rows equation appears fine here. I tried defining all 10 columns in targets, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you've swapped `columnDefs` and `columns`:

```
columnDefs: inquirySelectTableColumns,
columns: inquiryColumnDefs,
```

**Interchange** them and it'll work fine:

```
columnDefs: inquiryColumnDefs,
columns: inquirySelectTableColumns,
```

Example fork:
http://jsfiddle.net/bsf69o04/

Comment: Thank you. It worked! I can't believe I spent almost a day with my eyes closed like this.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, it happens. A fresh set of eyes did the trick. Happy coding!